# Ozone time series

Tags: r, date, datetime

I’m working with a time series of continued measurement of ozone concentration in ambient air over a 4 month period. Measurement are conducted every 5min14 sec. Approximately 40000 data points.

I started processing my data in R, but ran into some problems due to my lack of skills.

My data.frame is Date as characters and ozone concentration as numeric values.

```
     Date                     O3_ppb
   2018-05-26 17:55:58 UTC    33.95161
   2018-05-26 18:01:12 UTC    35.12605 
   2018-05-26 18:06:28 UTC    36.03172 
   2018-05-26 18:11:42 UTC    36.81590
   2018-05-26 18:16:57 UTC    37.11235 
   2018-05-26 18:22:12 UTC    37.26945
```

I wish to illustrate the daily development of ozone concentration over the course of 24h based on one month of data. Meaning I would like a monthly average every 5min over 24h.

My thinking was that I somehow need to sort my data into groups every 5min over 24h. For example 00:00:00, 00:05:00, 00:10:00 …
But since there is drift in the measurement a measurement conducted at 00:05:00 one day would be conducted 00:06:20 the next and so on. And since the sensor once in while reboot the number of observations each day fluctuates a bit aswell.

My question:
Is there a function or loop that would be able to sort my data into intervals of 5mins that also would be able to take drift into account, so that measurements that for example falls between 00:02:30 - 00:07:30 would be sorted into a group called 00:05:00 and 00:07:30 – 00:12:30 into a 00:10:00 group?

Sorry if this is completely unintelligible, but I’m new to R and in general programming. I really hope that someone can help me, so I can kick-start the project

Comment: Your looking for the `aggregate` function https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.2/topics/aggregate  as it will allow you to aggregate your data by YYYY-MM-DD, and you can use the function `average`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` approach using an overlap-join (`foverlaps()`)

```
library( data.table )

dt <- fread(' Date                     O3_ppb
            "2018-05-26 17:55:58"    33.95161
            "2018-05-26 18:01:12"    35.12605 
            "2018-05-26 18:06:28"    36.03172 
            "2018-05-26 18:11:42"    36.81590
            "2018-05-26 18:16:57"    37.11235 
            "2018-05-26 18:22:12"    37.26945', header = TRUE)

#set to posix
dt[, Date := as.POSIXct( Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC") ]
#create dummy variables to join on later
dt[, `:=`( Start = Date, Stop = Date ) ]

#create data.table with periods you wish to summarise on later
#notice the +/- 150 (=00:02:30) to set a 5 minute 'bandwidth' around the period.
dt.period <- data.table( period = seq( as.POSIXct( "2018-05-26 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC" ),
                                  as.POSIXct( "2018-05-27 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC" ),
                                  by = "5 mins"),
                         Start = seq( as.POSIXct( "2018-05-26 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC" ) - 150,
                                      as.POSIXct( "2018-05-27 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC" ) - 150 ,
                                      by = "5 mins"),
                         Stop = seq( as.POSIXct( "2018-05-26 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC" ) + 150,
                                     as.POSIXct( "2018-05-27 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC" ) + 150,
                                     by = "5 mins") )

#perform overlap join
#first set keys
setkey(dt.period, Start, Stop)
#then perform join
result <- foverlaps( dt, dt.period, type = "within", nomatch = NA )
#summarise
result[, .( O3_ppb_avg = mean( O3_ppb, na.rm = TRUE ) ), by = .(period) ]
```

**output**

```
#                 period O3_ppb_avg
# 1: 2018-05-26 17:55:00   33.95161
# 2: 2018-05-26 18:00:00   35.12605
# 3: 2018-05-26 18:05:00   36.03172
# 4: 2018-05-26 18:10:00   36.81590
# 5: 2018-05-26 18:15:00   37.11235
# 6: 2018-05-26 18:20:00   37.26945
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate that you took you time to do this.

I just encountered another problem. Whenever an ozone concentration doesn’t match a specified time interval it just removes that point. Is it possible to add something to the code, so whenever a date encounters a non-fitting ozone concentration it adds a new row with NA value? So in the end each day have exactly identical time intervals.

Comment: @MSM periods that are not found should not get removed, due to the `nomatch = NA` in the `foverlaps()`... make sure to check `result` directly after executing the `foverlaps` to make sure they aren't deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `lubridate` that just rounds to the closest 5 min, regardless of the time.

```
# Load data
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate)
df <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F,
text = "Date                     O3_ppb
   '2018-05-26 17:55:58 UTC'    33.95161
   '2018-05-26 18:01:12 UTC'    35.12605 
   '2018-05-26 18:06:28 UTC'    36.03172 
   '2018-05-26 18:11:42 UTC'    36.81590
   '2018-05-26 18:16:57 UTC'    37.11235 
   '2018-05-26 18:22:12 UTC'    37.26945") %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd_hms(Date))


df2 <- df %>%
     # By adding 2.5 min = 150 sec and rounding down, we get closest 5 min
     mutate(Date_rnd = floor_date(Date + 150, "5 minutes"),

     # One option is to group by decimal time of day 
     group    = hour(Date_rnd) + minute(Date_rnd)/60,

     # ...or could convert that to a time on a single day, in this case today
     group_as_datetime = floor_date(Sys.time(), "1 day") + group*60*60)
```

#### Output

```
> df2
#                 Date   O3_ppb            Date_rnd    group   group_as_datetime
#1 2018-05-26 17:55:58 33.95161 2018-05-26 17:55:00 17.91667 2019-01-05 17:55:00
#2 2018-05-26 18:01:12 35.12605 2018-05-26 18:00:00 18.00000 2019-01-05 18:00:00
#3 2018-05-26 18:06:28 36.03172 2018-05-26 18:05:00 18.08333 2019-01-05 18:05:00
#4 2018-05-26 18:11:42 36.81590 2018-05-26 18:10:00 18.16667 2019-01-05 18:10:00
#5 2018-05-26 18:16:57 37.11235 2018-05-26 18:15:00 18.25000 2019-01-05 18:15:00
#6 2018-05-26 18:22:12 37.26945 2018-05-26 18:20:00 18.33333 2019-01-05 18:20:00
```